# Jvectormap simple html in label

Tags: label, jvectormap

I'am new with Jvectormap and it is really great !!!
I just want to do something simple but I don't know how (no knowledge in JavaScript)
How can I have two lines in a label (html with break) ?

Example (marker):
`name: 'Rio de Janeiro', population:'6,323 millions',`

To have in the label :
**Rio de Janeiro**
**6,323 millions**

I hope that you can help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Look here: http://jvectormap.com/tutorials/data-visualization/.

You can see how the label is constructed:

```
onMarkerLabelShow: function(event, label, index){
  label.html(
    '<b>'+data.metro.names[index]+'</b><br/>'+'<b>Population:</b>'+data.metro.population[val][index]+'</br>'+'<b>Unemployment rate: </b>'+data.metro.unemployment[val][index]+'%'
  );
}
```

Check the result here: http://jvectormap.com/examples/usa-unemployment/